# Check if a String equals the name of an Enum constant

Tags: java, enums

I would like to check if a given String equals any Enum constant names in my Enum class. Here is an example:

```
public enum Relation { 
    APPLE("an apple"), 
    BANANA("a banana"); 

    private String value; 

    private Relation(String s) { 
        this.value = s; 
    } 

    public String getValue() { 
        return this.value; 
    }
}
```

My String would be:

```
String test = "a banana";
```

I want to check is the String equals any of the Enum constant names, i.e. "an apple" or "a banana":

```
if (test.equals(....)) {
 System.out.println("You ordered a banana.");
 }
```

So far, the examples I found all apply to checking if a String equals an Enum constant. But I want to check if the String equals any of the constant's names as defined in the parenthesis.

Comment: Show all the code of your enum; the code you show now will not even compile

Comment: Why can't you just declare `test` as a `Relation` type?

Comment: `public enum Relation {
  APPLE("an apple"),
  BANANA("a banana"); private String value; private Relation(String s) { this.value = s; } public String getValue() { return this.value; } and you can use this like that : Relation.BANANA.getValue();
}`

Comment: That's not an `enum` constant's name. That's a constructor argument that will presumably be assigned to a field. Compare with the `enum` constant's field (accessed in whichever way you expose it).

Comment: `if (test.equals(Relation.BANANA.getValue())) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a map/ or set to store the enum values, which you would then be able to check for matching values.

This would only be useful if you wanted to do this repeatedly, and reuse the map or set. You would use the map if you wanted to get the related enum.

```
    Map<String, Relation> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (Relation relation : Relation.values()) {
        map.put(relation.getValue(), relation);
    }

    if(map.containsKey("a banana")){
        System.out.println("You ordered a banana.");
    }
```

or as a set:

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Relation relation : Relation.values()) {
        set.add(relation.getValue());
    }

    if(set.contains("a banana")){
        System.out.println("You ordered a banana.");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Peter, I think your solution fits my purposes best because I will have to do the check repeatedly. I thought however, there would be a way to avoid a loop but apparently I'll have to use one.

Comment: @YourReflection, there is no way around the loop. When I use this in actual code, I tend to create a static final field with an `unmodifiableMap`, so that the map is always ready for use when the code runs.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Relation relation : Relation.values()) {
   if (relation.getValue().equals(string)) {
      return relation;
   }
}
return null;
```